# How do I make html select box default to most recent db entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an html select box that is populated by an array from the db. All the data in this table including the select box it written to a new table in the db along with current date. When the user returns to the class I want the select box to default to the last entry the user submitted whether it be the day before or a week before. I can get the query pretty close to where I need it but I dont really where to start as far as passing that to the select box.

Here is my select box that is echo from php.

```
    <td>
              <select name="movement[]" width=200>
              <option>Select...</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_01']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_02']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_03']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_04']). '</option>
        </select></td>
```

Here is the code for the entire array that is echo out.

```
    if(empty($workout_class) === false)
{   
foreach($workout_class as $wc){
if ($wc['pagenum'] !== $pagenum) continue 1;

    echo '<tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="client_id[]" value="'.($wc['client_id']).'">
        <input type="hidden" name="first_name[]" value="'.($wc['first_name']).'">'. ($wc['first_name']).'
        <span><input type="hidden" name="nickname[]" value="'.($wc['nickname']).'">('. ($wc['nickname']).')</span>
        <span><input type="hidden" name="last_name[]" value="'.($wc['last_name']).'">'. ($wc['last_name']).'</span>
        </td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="'.($wc['order']).'">'. ($wc['order']). '</td>
              <td>
              <select name="movement[]" width=200>
              <option>Select...</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_01']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_02']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_03']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_04']). '</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="rep_set_sec[]" value="'.($wc['rep_set_sec']).'">'. ($wc['rep_set_sec']). '</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="rest[]" value="'.($wc['rest']).'">'. ($wc['rest']). '</td>
        <td>00</td>
        </tr>';    
   } // foreach($data_array
```

Can this be done with php or is this something where js would be better?

OK, here is my variable that get the last movement entered based on the class, client and order.

```
    $recent_movement = recent_movement($class_id, $client_id, $order);
```

Here is my query that returns the array of movements from db based on MAX(date)

```
function recent_movement($class_id, $client_id, $order){
    $class_id = (int)$class_id;
    $client_id = (int)$client_id;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `movement` FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id' AND `client_id` = '$client_id' AND `order` = '$order' AND
`date` = (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM `completed_movements` WHERE `order` = '$order')");

$last_movement = mysql_fetch_array($query);

return $last_movement['movement'];

}
```

This is where Im not sure how to tell the select menu to set select="selected" based on what my $recent_movement returns.

Comment: Where do you store the user's most recent selection? If it's in the database, just compare the value of the most-recent selection to each option. If their values match, add the `selected` attribute to that option. It's really *that* straightforward.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: @Matt I have seen where the PDO is the way is should be and I plan to go back and revise once it complete. I just started it this way and Im pretty new to PHP so I figured I would keep it this way and go back and update once Im done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for argument's sake, let's say that you store the latest selection in `$recent_movement`. Just compare the value of that variable to the value of the options, and set the matching option to "selected":

```
<?php
.
.
.
echo '...

    <option' . ($ws['mv_00'] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>
    <option' . ($ws['mv_01'] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>'. ($wc['mv_01']). '</option>
    <option' . ($ws['mv_02'] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>'. ($wc['mv_02']). '</option>
    <option' . ($ws['mv_03'] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>'. ($wc['mv_03']). '</option>
    <option' . ($ws['mv_04'] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>'. ($wc['mv_04']). '</option>

...';
```

You can also simplify this by implementing a loop with a counter:

```
<?php

$options = "";
for($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $options .= '<option' . ($ws['mv_0' . $i] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>'. ($wc['mv_0' . $i]). '</option>';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Had this been my own code, I would have made some minor changes. Instead of that ***huge*** echo, I would have just exited PHP mode and gone with straight HTML. I would have also used my looping string constructor (posted above) for the `options`:

```
<?php
foreach ($workout_class as $wc) :
    if ($wc['pagenum'] !== $pagenum) continue 1;

    $options = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        $options .= '<option' . ($ws['mv_0' . $i] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"' : "") . '>' . ($wc['mv_0' . $i]) . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="client_id[]" value="<?= $wc['client_id'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="first_name[]" value="<?= $wc['first_name'] ?>"><?= $wc['first_name'] ?>
            <span><input type="hidden" name="nickname[]" value="<?= $wc['nickname'] ?>">(<?= $wc['nickname'] ?>)</span>
            <span><input type="hidden" name="last_name[]" value="<?= $wc['last_name'] ?>"><?= $wc['last_name'] ?></span>
        </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="<?= $wc['order'] ?>"><?= $wc['order'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <select name="movement[]" width=200>
                <option>Select...</option>
                <?= $options ?>
            </select></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="rep_set_sec[]" value="<?= $wc['rep_set_sec'] ?>"><?= $wc['rep_set_sec'] ?></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="rest[]" value="<?= $wc['rest'] ?>"><?= $wc['rest'] ?></td>
        <td>00</td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hey @Matt there is a parse error in this line and I can not figure out what it might be. `<option' . ($ws['mv_00'] == $recent_movement ? ' selected="selected"') . '>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>`

Comment: @Colbyd Sorry, I forgot the `else` part of the ternary operator. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks guys it works pefect. For sake or possibly learning something else today. Is this how you would of accomplished this had it been your own development?

Comment: @Colbyd check my updated answer for how I would have done it.

Comment: Thanks @Matt that helps to see it that way.

Answer (score 2):

if you had

```
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
```

When to pick "B" you would do

```
<option>A</option>
<option selected="selected">B</option>
<option>C</option>
```

As a result all you need to do is get the last value you wanted, and then for each output, if the value is the one you wanted add the "selected = ..." part.

(Edited to set value of selected to selected)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `selected = "true"`? I recall having problems with Internet Explorer (I forget which version) if the value of `selected` was anything other than `true` or `false`.

Comment: Cant say I ever ran into that, selected is the value the variable returns, so, Id have thought the actual option value would be more useful - I've used this a fair few times.

Comment: Most browsers don't care, but I think IE7 had an issue with it. Anyway, I just checked up on it, and we're both wrong. The value of the `selected` attribute should be "selected" ([source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/selected))

Comment: @BugFinder @Matt I have edited/add some code to the top to show what I'm having trouble with. I dont fully understand how to implement the `selected="selected` based on what is returned from my query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You split your echo where the  tags are.
Then , you iterate through them and when you reach the one that you wish to set as default you simply set

```
<option selected="selected" value="value">Option</option>
```

In this way this option will be the default one when entering the page.
This will work in your case.

---

I do not recommend using echo to build your page. You should instead rely on a template engine in your application. I recommend [Twig Template Engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) .

Comment: OP, You don't need a template engine. You can print your output as HTML, with the variables inserted using `<?= $var ?>`. While a templating engine is helpful, it might be the wrong path for you to take *at this particular moment*.